# For loop gives Undefined variable

Tags: php, for-loop

So I have five member-variables, but instead of writing:

```
if(isset($_POST['member1'])) {
    $member1 = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['member1']);
} else {
    $member1= '';
}
```

for all of the members (which gives no error), I want to do a for loop, but everytime I run the loop:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST['member . $i'])) {
            $member . $i = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['member . $i']);
        } else {
            $member . $i = '';
        }
}
```

I recieve this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: member
```

five times. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice two errors in your code:

- You're doing `$_POST['member . $i']` -- variable values aren't interpolated when they're in single quotes. You should either use double-quotes, or concatenate them properly
- You're trying to declare variables using `$member . $i` -- it wouldn't work either. You need to define them using the `${}` syntax. For example: `${'member'. $i}`

Try this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST['member' . $i])) {
        ${'member'. $i} = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['member' . $i]);
    } else {
        ${'member'. $i} = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it needs to be `$_POST['member' . $i]`

Than you trying to use variable `$member` to concatenate with it but it isn't exist.